# Error permission com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider

Tags: android, permissions, huawei-mobile-services

I have a problem with permission on android 6.
I'm trying to upload a file from the device to the server. If I try with the android emulator there is no problem. The app asks for permission and the uploads the file on the server. Instead if I try to upload the file from my Huawei p8 lite, the app crashs with the error:

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider from pid=3472, uid=10019 requires com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS: uid 10019 does not have com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1602)
                                                          at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                          at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                          at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
                                                          at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:437)
                                                          at com.huawei.keyguard.support.LauncherInteractiveUtil$Caller.run(LauncherInteractiveUtil.java:59)
                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

The function:

```
FloatingActionButton add=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_send_content);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            EditText ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_insertTitle);
            EditText ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_insertDescr);


            String titolo= ed1.getText().toString();
            String descrizione= ed2.getText().toString();




            if (fileAdded) {
                String path=ed4.getText().toString();
                String nome=getLastToken(path,"/");
                String []params1= {path,titolo};
                String[] s = {titolo, descrizione,nome};

                new InsertContentMetaData().execute(s);


                new InsertFile().execute(params1);
                Intent intent1=new Intent(NewContentActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                finish();

            }else{
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No file uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }


        }

    });


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            openPDF();
            String path=ed4.getText().toString();
            if (path!= null) {
                Log.d("Sono entrato","ciao");
                Log.d("DOPO OPEN PDF",path);

                fileAdded=true;

            }
        }


}
```

And finally the permission on Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE" />
```

Comment: did you get the solution? because i am facing the same issue.

Comment: any solution ? facing the same

Comment: It seems that they had the same problem
See here https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/issues/117
Hope it helps